# XAML event handler in a nonroot object

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

Imagine the following XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject">

   <local:MyStackPanel>
       <Button Content="Go" Click="OnGo"/>
   </local:MyStackPanel>
</Page>
```

XAML assumes that `OnGo`is a method in the page class. Can I somehow tell it **declaratively** that `OnGo` resides in `MyStackPanel` instead?

I know I can assign the event handler programmatically once the page is loaded. I'm wondering if it's possible by purely XAML means. "No" is an acceptable answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you could bind the MyStackPanel `DataContext` with itself. Then create  `BtnClickCommand` that used to bind button command in the `MyStackPanel` class  like following.

```
public class MyStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    public MyStackPanel()
    {

    }

    public ICommand BtnClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {


            });
        }
    }

}
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when RaiseCanExecuteChanged is called.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this RelayCommand can execute in its current state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">
    /// Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed,
    /// this object can be set to null.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the RelayCommand on the current command target.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">
    /// Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed,
    /// this object can be set to null.
    /// </param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to raise the CanExecuteChanged event
    /// to indicate that the return value of the CanExecute
    /// method has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<local:MyStackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
    <Button Command="{Binding BtnClickCommand}" Content="ClickMe" />
</local:MyStackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks. Hardly declarative, though.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev  Does this answer not meet the requirements?

Comment: There are no requirements, just a hope that XAML was more flexible that I knew :) Apparently not.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, All right, Xaml was inflexible. it can't do what you want. You are welcome to post  on the [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/).